# How do i send a mail using wp_mail in local it doesnt work

Tags: php, wordpress, post, localhost, wp-mail

I am running this in my localhost. when i publish a post nothing happens. I have added this in my themes functions.php file. How do i check the error? I dont see any error. I am new to development.

```
add_action('publish_post', 'sendnotification');
        
function sendnotification($post_id) {
   $post = get_post($post_id);
   $author = get_userdata($post->post_author);
   //  $user_email = get_the_author_meta( 'user_email' , $author_id );
   $subject = "Post Published: ".$post->post_title."";
             
   $message = "
      Hi ".$author->display_name.",
      Your post, \"".$post->post_title."\" has just been published.
      View post: ".get_permalink( $post_id )."
      Thanks"
   ;
   $sent = wp_mail($author->user_email, $subject, $message);
   if($sent) {
      echo "sent";
   }//mail sent!
   else  {
      echo "failed";
   }//message wasn't sent
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "nothing happens"? What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Use 
try { // your code (use it inside function) } catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
}
To check if there is a any error.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php#language.exceptions.catch

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15965376/how-to-configure-xampp-to-send-mail-from-localhost please see this thread

Comment: @NicoHaase - Nothing happens means mail is not sent. Nor i got any error. 
So i tried adding wp_error() and got below error when clicked on ADD NEW POST:

WP_Error Object
(
    [errors] => Array
        (
            [wp_mail_failed] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Invalid address:  (From): wordpress@localhost
                )

        )
Can you please suggest

Comment: Is there anything unclear about that error message? Also, please add all clarification to your question by editing it

Comment: What OS ar you using? the mail (from PHP) works different for every one. For example, on linux you can do it easy installing and starting postfix.

Comment: I am using MACBook Air, error indicates that the FROM address is wrong and says Invalid.
i get an error--> [0] => Invalid address: (From): wordpress@localhost

I understood that the issue is with from address. I need to set the from address.

I did set from address using header like below :
$headers = "From: Lavanya <lavanyacs5@gmail.com>;";  
 this doesn’t work. 
or should i use WP mail SMTP